# Calling Stored Procedure using iBatis

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ibatis

I have the following iBatis statement:

```
<select id="validateLogin" parameterType="Account" statementType="CALLABLE">
    { CALL PROC_LOGIN
        (
            #{account_name, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=IN},
            #{password, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=IN},
            #{fname, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=OUT},
            #{lname, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=OUT},
            #{account_name, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=OUT},
            #{status, jdbcType=INTEGER, mode=OUT},
            #{loginStatus, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=OUT}
        )
    }
</select>
```

However I'm getting, `Attribute "parameterType" must be declared for element type "select"` and `Attribute "statementType" must be declared for element type "select"`.

I'm new to iBatis and I haven't had much look searching on the internet on how to resolve this.

Comment: what about using parameterMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling it using "procedure" and "parameterMap" tags. Example ([more information here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ibatis/ibatis_stored_procedures.htm)):

```
<procedure id="getEmpInfo" resultClass="Employee" parameterMap="getEmpInfoCall">
   { call getEmp( #acctID# ) } 
</procedure>
<parameterMap id="getEmpInfoCall" class="map">
   <parameter property="acctID" jdbcType="INT" javaType="java.lang.Integer" mode="IN"/>
</parameterMap>
```

Comment: but it shows me the following error >>>  com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMap/procedure'.  Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: There is no parameter map named Employee.getEmpInfoCall in this SqlMap.